# Rails Geocoder Gem Passenger Failed to Start

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an odd problem. I created a geocoder.rb initializer file to use yahoo boss as my geo coding service. In turn, on my dev server everything seems to be working fine.  However, when I upload geocoder.rb to my initializers in production passenger fails to start properly due to the geocoder.rb file.  Gem list shows for geocoder: geocoder (1.1.6, 1.1.5)

This is what my geocoder.rb file looks like:

```
  Geocoder.configure(
:lookup => :yahoo,
:api_key => ['test', 'test']
 )
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Uninstalled all versions of geocoder and added this to gem file:

```
 gem "geocoder", "~> 1.1.6"
```